# Gzipping file on GCS (Google Cloud Storage) via Java API

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I have log files being dropped into a GCS bucket regularly (e.g. `gs://my-bucket/log.json`)  I want to setup a java process to process the files, gzip them, and move them to a separate bucket where I archive files (i.e. move it to `gs://archived-logs/my-bucket/log.json.gz`)

`gsutil cp -z` seems to be the only option I can find currently. Has anybody implemented it in a feasible manner using their Java API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved it. Standard streams solution in the ending.

```
    GcsOutputChannel gcsOutputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(new GcsFilename("my-bucket", "log.json.gz"),
    new GcsFileOptions.Builder().build());
    GZIPOutputStream outputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(gcsOutputChannel));

    GcsInputChannel inputChannel = gcsService
                    .openReadChannel(new GcsFilename("my-bucket", "log.json"), 10000);

    InputStream inStream = Channels.newInputStream(inputChannel);
    byte[] byteArr = new byte[10000];
    while (inStream.read(byteArr) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(byteArr);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the latest streaming writer you can follow the below code. Do note that gcp will automatically decompress the object while serving it to web clients. If it doesnt work then add the following header to accept gzip files, "Accept-Encoding": "gzip".

```
    Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(environmentConfig.getServiceAccount())));
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(environmentConfig.getProjectID()).setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

    try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo)) {
        GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new 
        GZIPOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(writer));
        gzipOutputStream.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(objectData, 0, objectData.length).array());
        gzipOutputStream.flush();
        gzipOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error("Upload Error: {}", ex.getMessage());
    }
```